# How can one check how long he is in the penalty box?

Tags: support, account-suspension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)

Apparently, I was sent to the penalty box. I was looking [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) and saw that it said, *"Your user page will have a visual indication that you are in timed suspension, and for how long."* I checked my profile and I don't see any visual indication.

Edit: My Stackoverflow account got in the penalty box.

I get this message when trying to create a question, *"Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more."*

Comment: Which account? You have several.

Comment: [You're not in any penalty boxes at the moment](http://stackoverflow.com/users/546476/dan-the-man). If it was a short ban, say 1 day, then you may never have seen it happen.

Comment: Stackoverflow account

Comment: You have too many low quality questions.

Answer (score 2):

Your account is not suspended; if it were, then, as reported in [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/):

- Your account would be locked at 1 reputation.
- Your user page would have a visual indication that you are in timed suspension, and for how long.
- You would be unable to vote, ask, answer, or comment.

You cannot ask questions because a question ban automatically triggered by the quality of your previous questions. Differently from a suspension, there isn't a visual indication of an account being banned from asking questions.

Comment: Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: @Dan You cannot: "Once you have posted too many bad quality questions, you will be banned from asking more, and see the error message. You can then still use the site, except for asking questions."

Comment: that's terrible!